# How to get video url from metadata received in Vimeo API

Tags: url, video

I want to get url of all videos for an album on Vimeo. For this first of all I am using PHP libraries to get a list of albums on Vimeo by following code.

```
$api_endpoint = 'http://vimeo.com/api/v2/' . $vimeo_user_name;

$albums = simplexml_load_string(curl_get($api_endpoint . '/albums.xml'));

    <? foreach($albums->album as $album) { 
    echo $album->id 

    //After getting album id i have to get url of all videos for this album id in next foreach loop

    $AlbumVideos = curl_get($api_endpoint . '/' . $album->id . '/videos');
        foreach($AlbumVideos->video as $video) 
        {echo video->url;}
    } ?>
```

I got error here $AlbumVideos->video as $video as i am not able to guess the data structure for $AlbumVideos. 
Need help please.

Thanks in advance